# Two different Facebook share links on one page

Tags: facebook

I am trying to add Two different Facebook share links on one page.

I have this one:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/Start"/>
```

That one is to share a background image. I need to make another one for a contest is it possible.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: That is not a “Facebook share link”, that is _meta data_ describing the content of your page. And no, this is not possible. You would have to share two different URLs, so that each one can return one distinctive set of meta data when requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/Start"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="XXX is Cape Breton's Homepage"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="* The Northeast Margaree River from Doyles Bridge in the morning *"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/Start/images/backgrounds/bg9.jpg"/>
```